# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python

```
def male_resting_metabolic_rate(weight,height,age):

  '''Takes in the weight, height, and age of a male individual
  and returns the resting metabolic rate

Example answers: 
    male_resting_metabolic_rate(80,180,48) = 1751'''

   male_resting_metabolic_rate = int((88.4+13.4*weight)+(4.8*height)-(5.68* age))

 if __name__ == "__main__":
print("This program will calculate the resting metabolic rate of an individual")

  #Gather the inputs for the functions 

 weight = input("What is your weight in kilograms?")
 height = input("What is your height in centimeters?")
 age = int(input("What is your age?" + "(between 1-110):"))

 print("Your resting metabolic rate is",male_resting_metabolic_rate(input,input,input))
```

Why is it saying that I have an error in line 10 and 24? Super new to this so my apologies if the answer is fairly obvious.

Comment: `input,input,input` : 3 times the `input` method instead of the variables you defined above!! Also you're missing the conversion to integers for 2 variables.

Comment: There's a number of issues here. The first is that `input` returns a string, so you would need to convert weight to something numerical before multiplying it. `male_resting_metabolic_rate(input,input,input))` doesn't make sense, what were you trying to do?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How do i convert the variables into integers? Again I apologize I feel like this is really basic!

Comment: You already did it for `age` with `int()`

Comment: You cannot do that, your intent clicked for me later on. You already ask for `weight`, `height` and `age` as inputs. You need to pass those as arguments to the function so: `male_resting_metabolic_rate(weight, height, age)`. But your function doesn't return anything (actually it overwrites its own name because you have `male_resting_metabolic_rate = int((88.4+13.4*weight)+(4.8*height)-(5.68* age))`). You shouldn't have two things called `male_resting_metabolic_rate`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Spotted at least two mistakes: You need to return the value with "return" in python. Also you needed to pass the parameters by name not "input"

try this:

```
def male_resting_metabolic_rate(weight,height,age):

  '''Takes in the weight, height, and age of a male individual
  and returns the resting metabolic rate

  Example answers: 
    male_resting_metabolic_rate(80,180,48) = 1751'''

    return int((88.4+13.4*weight)+(4.8*height)-(5.68* age))

 if __name__ == "__main__":
   print("This program will calculate the resting metabolic rate of an individual")

   #Gather the inputs for the functions 

   weight = float(input("What is your weight in kilograms?"))
   height = float(input("What is your height in centimeters?"))
   age = int(input("What is your age?" + "(between 1-110):"))

   print("Your resting metabolic rate is",male_resting_metabolic_rate(weight, height, age ))
```

Comment: I was just finalising a solution for this. Please don't post an answer with all the messed up formatting in the question, you need to fix it in an editor.

Comment: @roganjosh I apologize for that - I did not know how to format code and comments in the same reply. I figured out the problem though, thank you so much!

Comment: @J.Lee you use backticks for formatting in a comment. For code blocks you can copy/paste, highlight the whole thing and use `ctrl` + `k`. However, this answer also needs its formatting improving. There's no reason for badly formatted questions and answers.